# aliasing confusion - what mapped 'vm' to 'Get-VM'?

Tags: powershell, vmware, alias

Intending to launch vim from this

```
PS C:\temp> get-command vim | select name,source

Name    Source
----    ------
vim.bat C:\Users\noam\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\vim.bat
```

I accidentally entered `vm` instead of `vim` and much head-scratching has ensued:

```
C:\temp>pwsh -noprofile
PowerShell 7.4.1
PS C:\temp> vm
Get-VM: 29-Mar-24 16:28:14      Get-VM          You are not currently connected to any servers. Please connect first using a Connect cmdlet.
PS C:\temp> get-command vm
Get-Command: The term 'vm' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
PS C:\temp> get-alias vm
Get-Alias: This command cannot find a matching alias because an alias with the name 'vm' does not exist.
PS C:\temp> cmd /c where vm
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
```

How to find and remove the config that has seemingly mapped `vm` to `Get-VM` from VMware's PowerCLI?

```
PS C:\temp> get-command get-vm | select Name,Source

Name   Source
----   ------
Get-VM VMware.VimAutomation.Core
```

I must be missing something silly. I would have thought the above call to `where.exe` should have uncovered anything relevant on my path. Anyway the behavior does not change after setting `$env:PATH = $null`.

As a kludge I could explicitly redefine `vm` via `Set-Alias` to some non-existent command. But I'd like to understand why I don't see something like below when executing `vm`. What have I overlooked?

```
PS C:\temp> doesnotexist
doesnotexist: The term 'doesnotexist' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

Above results have been reproducible with and without the `VMware.VimAutomation.Core` module explicitly imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an "aliasing-issue" it's part of PowerShell's "verb-first" approach to command naming.

PowerShell automatically assumes the `Get-` verb on cmdlets when no verb is specified.

You can try that out by simply writing some commands like `childitem`, `location` etc. it will automatically run `Get-ChildItem` and `Get-Location`

This also explains the behaviours of the different cmdlets you tried to find out about this behaviour:

- `Get-Command vm` - since vm isn't the command, it was not found.
- `Get-Alias vm` - since it also isn't an alias, you couldn't find it here either.

This behaviour does not apply to user-defined functions or console applications, that's why you can create functions called `DoStuff` and PowerShell won't automatically do `Get-DoStuff`

You can't change this behaviour, but you could create a `vm` function that does something else, if you really want to do that.

Comment: Thank you! Silly of me not to have tried other command nouns. I’ll leave well enough alone, was less concerned about this particular command than the potential to unwittingly run something more dangerous. The Get- assumption is reassuring.